# How to compress multiple folders in the background, each into its own zip archive?

Tags: zip, nohup

I found that a great way to zip folders into their own zip files is through this loop:

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

But I wanted to do this all in the background (e.g., nohup &), but I cannot get it to work. How do I do this?

Comment: replace `zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; ` with `nohup zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" &` - note in particular there is no semicolon after the `&`

Answer (score 0):

You could execute your commands as a shell script, e.g.

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done' &
```

Comment: This does all the zips sequentially (albeit in the background). My reading of the question was to do them all in parallel.

Comment: Yes, nothing fancy here, just "Make the for-loop work with nohup".

Comment: Oh actually in parallel is not necessary as sequentially definitely works. Thanks so much this worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

The request is to do the compression in parallel.

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" & done' &
```

This will start one zip for each subdirectory. These jobs are started under a common nohup, which is itself backgrounded.